# Issues I resolved last yer JQL

Tags: jira, jql

I like to form a JQL query that finds "issues that was resolved by me last year".

I can't seem to get it right.

This is my query:

```
Resolution WAS Fixed BY currentUser(), DURING (endOfYear(), startOfYear())
```

I also tried following query:

```
Resolution DURING (endOfYear(), startOfYear()) was Fixed BY currentUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution for last year, you can use following query:

```
resolved >= startOfYear() and resolved <= endOfYear() and resolution CHANGED BY currentUser()
```

But, if you have some edge cases such as more than a few resolution; you also can filter it like that:

```
resolved >= startOfYear() and resolved <= endOfYear() and resolution in ('Fixed') and resolution CHANGED BY currentUser()
```

So, to sum up; there are two different keywords for the resolution:

1. **resolved**: Which covers the resolution date
2. **resolution**: Which is the resolution name

For their advanced JQL guide, you may check Resolved and Resolution sections in [this link in Atlassian docs](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-fields/).